# How to view the source code for the standard flash library?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Specifically `flash.display.BitmapData`.

I've seen the swc file, header-like classes, and some implementation files for

fl.*, but not flash.*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not until Adobe decides to open source for Flash platform runtime. These classes implemented in the player, most probably in C++. If you need them that bad, try to disassemble player...

Comment: Oh right, it didn't even occur to me that it wasn't open source. With dissemblers and reflectors why even bother?